# Sites which can be reached in a certain time

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, distance, cost-path

I'm trying to analyse the sourrounding of an archaeological site in QGIS. Therefore I've created a cost map with r.walk in GRASS (cumulative costs range from 10939500 to 14211500). 
Is there anly possibility to show only areas which can be reached in 1 h? My Point of Destination is a archaeology site and I want to know which setllements in the neighborhood can be reached in a 1 h walking distance. I'm not interrested in an exact least-cost-path solution but there must be a possibility to create a simple map, or am I wrong?

The solution must be easy but I'm totally lost.

Can you help me?

Comment: Perhaps interesting: there is a GRASS GIS addon "v.isochrones" - Creates isochrones from a road map and starting points, see https://grass.osgeo.org/grass70/manuals/addons/v.isochrones.html

Answer (score 1):

If I follow your question correctly(and what was posted to the GRASS maillist), then I guess you have:

1. A point vector of settlements (multiple settlements)
2. A second point vector of the archeology site (single point)
3. A raster map where each pixel represents the time of walking thru that cell

In this case I think that r.cost ([manual](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass70/manuals/r.cost.html)) and a simple r.mapcalc expression will do what you want.

First run r.cost with the walking time raster as input, use the settlements vector as start_points and the archeology site as stop_point, and call the output "accum_cost".
Then, assuming the walking time raster was in seconds, run:

```
r.mapcalc "within_1hr = if(accum_cost<=3600, 1, null())"
```

This should create a new raster such that all those areas within 1 hr walking will have value 1, and all other areas are null.

The added value of r.walk, vs the simpler r.cost, is the option to combine both an elevation layer **and** a friction layer. So if in your model, walking from the settlements to the site involves both climbing hills and i.e. cutting thru a jungle, then you could combine the costs of both with r.walk. You can even set the speed parameters (you've probably already seen the r.walk [manual](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass70/manuals/r.walk.html) for this.)